# magento custom CMS page add javascript

Tags: php, magento

i am following this howto to add a custom CMS page http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/adding_cms_layout_templates

the issue i am having is that i want to add a NivoSlider javascript just to this page and the only way to add it to the  is to do it through the Admin -> CMS -> Pages and then change the Layout Update XML by adding the

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addJs">
<script>nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js</script>
</action>
<action method="addCss">
<script>css/nivo-slider.css
</script></action>
</reference>
```

is there a way to add the javascript on the filesystem rather then through the Admin -> CMS -> Pages -> Page -> Layout Update XML interface?

any advise much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can override page.xml in your layouts folder of your theme and add the script globally like,

```
<action method="addJs"><script>nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js</script></action>
```

Comment: yes i know that, the point is that i don't want to load the script globally as i only need it on this particular page.

Comment: Ah ok sorry that wasn't too clear from your question. That is how you do it through the file system. If you want to add it to a single page you can create a copy of the layout it is using ie 2 col left and then just add it into the header of the phtml file using the standard script tag. Then apply this layout only to the desired page. Little bit of a hack I guess and this probably comes too late

Answer (score 0):

You can just write the code directly to your CMS page in the backend as you would write it normally. You can just use `<style></style>` and/or `<script></script>` tags and write your CMS site specific code into it.